# Powershell Remote file copy is not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files remotely on several IIS servers from one source server.

`sourcepath` is a UNC path like `\\server\c$\path\` and `destinationpath` is a local folder `c:\data\destination\`

The strange thing is when I run this on  the local server this will work perfectly.

```
 $cmd = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
 $cmd.CommandText ="SELECT * from infrastructure"
 $Serverinfo = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
 try
 {
     while ($Serverinfo.Read())
     {
       $servername = $Serverinfo.GetValue(1)
       $location = $Serverinfo.GetValue(2)
       #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { new-item -Path $Using:destinationpath -name $Using:versionnumber -Itemtype directory }
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { Copy-Item -Path $Using:sourcepath -destination $Using:destinationpath }
       #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername {Import-Module WebAdministration ; New-WebApplication -force  -Site "Default Web Site" -Name $Using:versionnumber -PhysicalPath $Using:destinationpath$Using:versionnumber }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is the script throwing an error? If so, what error (paste it into your question)? Do you have a `catch` block for the `try` block shown here? If so, what does it do, and is it what is actually happening?

Comment: Hi, completely no errors :-(

Comment: What happens if you simplify the code down to the single command you're having issues with and hardcoded values? Do you get any errors? `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server01"  { Copy-Item -Path "\\server\c$\path\file.txt" -destination "c:\data\destination\" }`

Comment: Can you single-step through the script and examine the very (absolute) paths?

Comment: Can you show your catch block like Jeff was asking? What you show is not valid PowerShell without the catch block.

Comment: Where are $sourcepath and $destinationpath defined?

Comment: I have the same problem. No errors at all, but no files are copied.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is incomplete without a catch block and source and destination path defined as others said.

But what I can see here as a possible cause even if you mention all above three constrains.

You will face issues with credential delegation . You are remoting to one server using PSRP and copying one file to that machine and you are taking your source file from a UNC path which requires some authentication.

I could give you two better alternatives, of course 1st once could be the proper solution.

If you are in PS 5.o or later, you can use `-ToSession` parameter of `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
$Session  =    New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName
Copy-Item -SourcePath \\\Server\c$\path -Destination c:\data\Destination-ToSession $Session
```

For more info [Get-Help Copy-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Edit:

The second one:

```
Copy-Item -Path <Sourcepath> -DestinationPath \\destinataionserver\c$\folder
```

from source to the destination by accessing the shared folder of the destination system.

Comment: where is the second one? I don't have PS 5.0. I am running PS 3.